# Programmatic selection the active plugin of SLF4J

Tags: plugins, configuration, runtime, selection, slf4j

Is there a way to select programmatically the active SLF4J plugin in a context where multiple plugins are deployed and accessible via the classpath ?

Thanks

sebastien